# django concurrent bulk_create not inserting all values to database

Tags: django, python-3.x, concurrency, celery, bulkinsert

i'm using django's `bulk_create` to store large amount of data to postgresql database. This is happening inside a celery task. Many instance of this tasks are invoked at once based on different parameter values. There are 4 different workers which run each task instance in parallel. 
When only one task instance is run, all values are getting added to database but when multiple instances are running together via different workers, only some values are getting inserted

while creating a list of model objects for bulk_create, i added `print` to cross check if the value was getting inserted in the list. i found that the value is always added to the list but after bulk_create, the same values don't reflect in db. 
I had partially solved this issue by adding `time.sleep` to add latency and `batch_size` parameter in bulk_create. But this solution is not ideal and doesn't solve the issue anymore since the data has increased.

i cannot post exact code, but it is something like this:
* celery task:

```py
def some_function():
   param_lst=[1,3,..] #many values
   all_task=[]
   for i in param_lst:
      all_task.append(some_task1.si(i)) #some_task1 and some_task2 are using majorly similar code, only some data processing changes. both use bulk_create to store values
      all_task.append(some_task2.si(i))
   ch = chord( group( all_task )).set(queue="someQueue")(some_funct) #this is how the tasks are invoked

   if ch.ready():
       ch.get()
```

task function definition

```py
@someapp.task
def some_task1(self,i):
  #process/modify data based on param i
  #we end up with json and iterate over it
  batch = []
  for k in someDict:
    result=MyModel(val1=something,...) #all values inside model
    batch.append(result)
  MyModel.objects.bulk_create(batch) #also tried with batch_size parameter
```

the other task is similar except some changes in data modifications. it uses same way of `bulk_create` for storing values

There are no error messages thrown. when i run for just one param bulk_create stores all values but when the task is run for list of params in parallel, it will miss inserting some values to db.
I could not find anything like this while searching on web. 
I'm not that good with database concepts and very new to celery. please let me know if i'm missing something or doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a transaction around your bulk_create.  Depending on the backend, it may not otherwise be a transactional operation.

```
from django.db import transaction

@someapp.task
@transaction.atomic
def some_task1(self,i):
  #process/modify data based on param i
  #we end up with json and iterate over it
  batch = []
  for k in someDict:
    result=MyModel(val1=something,...) #all values inside model
    batch.append(result)
  MyModel.objects.bulk_create(batch) #also tried with batch_size parameter
```